# In Python Pandas, how to join on a datetime column another dataframe that is indexed by a periodindex?

Tags: python, datetime, join, pandas

I have two dataframes, df1, df2.

df1 has a column 'date', that is a datetime. df2 is indexed by a periodindex (periods of time, instead of timestamps).

I wish I could somehow join the two dataframes so that, for each row of df1, I will add all the columns of df2 for the row (in df2) selected by the periodindex where the df1['date'] belongs.

I hope the question is clear enough. I guess I can manually do some loop to do that, but if there is a more efficient way to do this, using some pandas method, I will appreciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Here are the first columns of df2, the data frame indexed by a periodindex called 'cuatrimestre':

```
                  dif_precio_vivienda  dif_rendimiento_ibex  \
cuatrimestre                                              
1995Q1                        NaN                   NaN   
1995Q2                   0.000000             -2.940238   
1995Q3                   0.007233             -0.500118   
1995Q4                   0.026514              0.535169   
1996Q1                  -0.009417             -0.171129
```

And here the first columns of df1:

```
    fecha  municipioid   latitud  longitud  numbanyo  numdormitorio  \
25138  2014-02-12         4353  0.705444 -0.064720       1.0            1.0   
25144  2014-05-06         4353  0.705444 -0.064720       1.0            1.0   
25185  2014-01-02         4353  0.705349 -0.064618       1.0            1.0   
25186  2014-02-12         4353  0.705353 -0.064620       1.0            1.0   
25201  2014-07-07         4353  0.705314 -0.064610       1.0            3.0
```

You can see that the index is diferent, but it has a datetime column ('fecha'), and I wanted to join on this column over the periodindex...

Comment: Can you add sample of dataframes?

Comment: Ok. I will edit the entry if I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first create columns `year` and `quarter` in both `DataFrames` by [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) in `df1` and [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with converting to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) in `df2`. Then you can [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) them by columns `year` and `quarter`:

```
#if type of column fecha is to datetime, convert it
df1['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['fecha'])
df1['year'] = df1['fecha'].dt.year
df1['quarter'] = df1['fecha'].dt.quarter
print df1
           fecha  municipioid   latitud  longitud  numbanyo  numdormitorio  \
25138 2014-02-12         4353  0.705444 -0.064720       1.0            1.0   
25144 2014-05-06         4353  0.705444 -0.064720       1.0            1.0   
25185 2014-01-02         4353  0.705349 -0.064618       1.0            1.0   
25186 2014-02-12         4353  0.705353 -0.064620       1.0            1.0   
25201 2014-07-07         4353  0.705314 -0.064610       1.0            3.0   

       year  quarter  
25138  2014        1  
25144  2014        2  
25185  2014        1  
25186  2014        1  
25201  2014        3  

df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2[['year','quarter']] = df2['cuatrimestre'].str.split('Q', expand=True)
df2['year'] = df2['year'].astype(int)
df2['quarter'] = df2['quarter'].astype(int)
print df2
  cuatrimestre  dif_precio_vivienda  dif_rendimiento_ibex  year  quarter
0       2014Q1                  NaN                   NaN  2014        1
1       2014Q2             0.000000             -2.940238  2014        2
2       1995Q3             0.007233             -0.500118  1995        3
3       1995Q4             0.026514              0.535169  1995        4
4       1996Q1            -0.009417             -0.171129  1996        1
```

```
print pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['year','quarter'], how='left')
       fecha  municipioid   latitud  longitud  numbanyo  numdormitorio  year  \
0 2014-02-12         4353  0.705444 -0.064720       1.0            1.0  2014   
1 2014-05-06         4353  0.705444 -0.064720       1.0            1.0  2014   
2 2014-01-02         4353  0.705349 -0.064618       1.0            1.0  2014   
3 2014-02-12         4353  0.705353 -0.064620       1.0            1.0  2014   
4 2014-07-07         4353  0.705314 -0.064610       1.0            3.0  2014   

   quarter cuatrimestre  dif_precio_vivienda  dif_rendimiento_ibex  
0        1       2014Q1                  NaN                   NaN  
1        2       2014Q2                  0.0             -2.940238  
2        1       2014Q1                  NaN                   NaN  
3        1       2014Q1                  NaN                   NaN  
4        3          NaN                  NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked nicely! I only had to adjust this line: 

df2[['year','quarter']] = df2['cuatrimestre'].str.split('Q', expand=True)

In order to convert to the str type: 

df2[['year','quarter']] = df2['cuatrimestre'].astype(str).str.split('Q', expand=True)

But yeah, it solved the issue. I really appreciate your effort and speed in providing the answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!